# Make two textareas side by side sharing a flexible border

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to make two textareas side by side, which share a same border. Then we could drag the border and change their width, while keeping the sum of their widths constant. In other words, it is like the panels inside JSBin.

Does anyone know how to realise this?

PS: here is the code to make two stationary textareas side by side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea name="t1"></textarea>
  <textarea name="t2"></textarea>   
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:** the following code is from `index.html` of JSBin. But I don't see how it manages to realise the sharing border:

```
  <div id="panelswaiting">
    <div class="code stretch html panel">
      <div role="menubar" class="label menu" tabindex="0"><span class="name"><strong><a href="#htmlprocessors" role="menuitem" class="fake-dropdown button-dropdown">Processor</a></strong></span><div class="dropdown" id="htmlprocessors">
          <div role="menu" aria-hidden="true" class="dropdownmenu processorSelector" data-type="html">
            <a role="menuitemradio" aria-checked="true" href="#html" data-label="HTML">HTML</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#markdown">Markdown</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#jade">Jade</a>
            <a href="#convert">Convert to HTML</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="editbox">
        <textarea aria-label="HTML Code Panel" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" id="html"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="code stretch javascript panel">
      <div role="menubar" class="label menu" tabindex="0"><span class="name"><strong><a role="menuitem" class="fake-dropdown button-dropdown" href="#javascriptprocessors">Processor</a></strong></span>
        <div class="dropdown" id="javascriptprocessors">
          <div role="menu" aria-hidden="true" class="dropdownmenu processorSelector" data-type="javascript">
            <a role="menuitemradio" aria-checked="true" href="#javascript" data-label="JavaScript">JavaScript</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#babel">ES6 / Babel</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#jsx">JSX (React)</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#coffeescript">CoffeeScript</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#traceur">Traceur</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#typescript">TypeScript</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#processing">Processing</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#livescript">LiveScript</a>
            <a role="menuitemradio" href="#clojurescript">ClojureScript</a>
            <a role="menuitem" href="#convert">Convert to JavaScript</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="editbox">
        <textarea aria-label="JavaScript Code Panel" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" id="javascript"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

**Edit 2:**

Following the answer of Ankit vadariya, I have made [a minimum case](https://jsbin.com/tajihi/7/edit?html,css,js,output)... There is only one thing left: how to ensure the `min-width` of `.panel-right`? It does not seem to work at the moment...

One way is to set `max-width` of `.panel-left`, but if we look at JSBin, there is no limit of `max-width` for each panel, whereas there is `min-width`...

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Look into this: `https://jqueryui.com/resizable/` you will need to have your text areas be 100% within the resizeable divs.

Comment: Here is [an example](https://jsbin.com/davedunuho/2/edit?html,output) with `resizable`, I don't see how to keep the sum of two widths constant.

Comment: that's not how the standard textareas work.  You'd have to create your own with JS, which is probably not what you actually want.

Comment: @andi, For example, JSBin still uses textareas. Please see my update.

Comment: @Thomas the <textarea>s that you see in that markup are actually hidden with CSS, and then everything else that you do see is built up with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the your solution](https://codepen.io/rstrahl/pen/eJZQej)

Hope it will work for you.

Code

```
$(".panel-left").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter",
   resizeHeight: false
 });

 $(".panel-top").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter-horizontal",
   resizeWidth: false
 });
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}


/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;  
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;  
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}


/* vertical panel */

.panel-container-vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-top {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter-horizontal {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/hsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

.panel-bottom {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
}

pre {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Split Panels - jquery-resizable</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body style="">
    <div class="page-container">

        <h1>
           jquery-resizable - A simple splitter panel
        </h1>
        <hr />

        <p>
            Simple example that demonstrates how to create slidable two-pane layouts <a href="http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox">using FlexBox</a> and the resizable plug-in.
            Note that Flexbox is not required, but used here to keep the layout simple.
        </p>

        <label>Horizontal Splitter Panes:</label>

        <div class="panel-container">

            <div class="panel-left">
                left panel
            </div>

            <div class="splitter">
            </div>

            <div class="panel-right">
                right panel
            </div>
        </div>

        <label>Vertical Splitter Panes:</label>
        <div class="panel-container-vertical">

            <div class="panel-top">
                top panel
            </div>

            <div class="splitter-horizontal">
            </div>

            <div class="panel-bottom">
                bottom panel
            </div>
        </div>



        <hr />

        <p>
            This example creates two resizables for the horizontal and vertical splitter panes:
        </p>
<pre>
&lt;script src=&quot;//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src=&quot;../src/jquery-resizable.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
    $(&quot;.panel-left&quot;).resizable({
        handleSelector: &quot;.splitter&quot;,
        resizeHeight: false
    });
    $(&quot;.panel-top&quot;).resizable({
        handleSelector: &quot;.splitter-horizontal&quot;,
        resizeWidth: false
    });
&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't show textareas, which the OP asked about specifically.

Comment: You can replace it with text area.

Comment: Make css like hide border of text area & make textarea 100% of parent div

Comment: thanks, I think that'll help him as long as he is OK with using that plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much, there is only one thing left, please see my update...

Comment: please add max-width:600px; in .panel-left class

Basically if its responsive then you need to apply max-width on pageload before resizable initialized

Comment: I have added `max-width:600px`, [it](https://jsbin.com/tajihi/15/edit?html,css,js,output) does not work...

Comment: I have updated please check and let me know
https://jsbin.com/fakotovaji/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I see... actually, I realise that we need to make the whole output panel wide enough to see the effect (minimum width) of the right panel.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this is using something like JavaScript and analyzing in real-time the width of one to get the other to add to 100%.